# Remove emergency mode permanently

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fsck, mode

I am currently having issues booting into my computer, I keep getting into emergency mode and my computer is unusable, more than likely this is a fsck issue but I am unable to fix it due to this mode which is supposed to help me, oh the irony, when i try to access to a recovery mode, to run fsck manually, my screen keeps switching between what I am supposed to look at, the recovery options and this "emergency mode", rendering any action I try to make impossible to accomplish, if i continue the boot process and make it to the emergency screen, I am not able to do fsck because at that point the partitions have been mounted and using unmount only says that the partition is being used and is unable to unmount the partition not even by using the force option and won't let me make the partition read only either, I want to disable this emergency mode so I can work as on the recovery menu normally, any help is appreciated and thank you for assistance

Comment: Did yuo use the livecd option? And you can unmount a currently used filesystem and please note the emergency mode is there to help so disabling it might not be a good idea!

Comment: I dont have the live CD with me unfortunately, I am using my cellphone to post in here, so even though I could download an. Iso I would not be able to create a live usb, I know that it should be possible to unmount a partition currently being used but the system is not doing it not even using the force option, I am aware that disabling the emergency option is not a good idea, but at the moment is what is getting in the way for me to fix the computer

Comment: Have you tried to remount the filesystem in read-only mode? A RO mounted file system can be checked.

Comment: I tried, but all I get is the message device is busy and I can't get past that

Comment: If it's merely an fsck-needed issue, then simply set the forcefsck flag (`touch /forcefsck`), then reboot.

Comment: After checking systemctl I can see that the issue is with fsck, I tried running the command above but I am stil getting to the emergency screen

Comment: But fsck ran? Please remember that we cannot see what you see. What exactly is "the issue" with fsck?

Comment: based on what I can see it ran, I did not get any error message but after rebooting I was sent again to the emergency screen, is there any way I can maybe go back to upstart, systemd is becoming more a headache than anything else at this point, and if is possible are there any downsides ?